# Where does Blazor store form data?

Tags: javascript, blazor

Interestingly, some input elements of [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) Forms don't have the data stored in HTML as value (attribute) of the input-field. The fields doesn't even have a value attribute!

When I inspect and use *'Store as global object'* functionality in chrome and check the value of the element in console (`temp1.value`), I can see the value.

I'm wondering where this value is being stored in the browser.

Comment: @schroeder thank you for the migration. I just noticed that Stackoverflow has a tag for blazor.

Comment: These values are not stored in the browser. The *input elements of Blazor Forms*
are rather class components written with C$, and have properties such as Value and  supporting fields where the values are stored and retrieved.


Whether Blazor makes a temporary use of local storage or not might be possible, but I've never bothered my self about that.

Comment: @enet, If I understand correctly, you mean to say that the data is stored in wasm (C# gets finally compiled into web-asm). But html renderer does not access wasm data directly (please correct if wrong). So, to display the data, it has to be present in html right? Actually, my interest is about if this mechanism can prevent XSS or not?

Comment: Your C£ code isn't complied to WebAssembly. Only the mono runtime is  complied to WebAssembly, your C£ code is complied to .Net Assemblies. Your question is interesting.. I've never bothered myself to ask where the data is exactly stored. I can speculate, but can't suggested any educated answer. Regarding XSS , you should treat your Blazor apps as if you are using JavaScript, as wasm apps use the same UI thread used by JavaScript, and constraint by the same limitations

Answer (score 0):

The value *attribute* is not set by changing the DOM's *.value* property.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
<input id=time>
<script>setInterval("time.value = new Date()", 1000);</script>
<input type=button onclick=alert(time.value) value=read>
```

You can inspect the clock and see that there's never a value attribute, yet the input's value property can be both setted and getted by script.

Thus, the *value* of the form input in your question can come from almost anywhere. It's likely embedded deep inside the other library support code that makes it easy to shuttle data back and forth, but that's speculation on my part. It's a JS variable of some sort, that much we know. The main thing is that *attributes* are not needed when making heavy use of JS.